# Select ALL columns in MySQL with one column inside CAST function

Tags: mysql

I basically want to select all columns of my MySQL table, but want to change the datatype of only one column namely `Patient_Number` using `CAST` function only. Here is a screenshot of my MySQL table

[image]

So as my output, I want a similar table as I have shown in the screenshot, just want to have the datatype of Patient_Number from INT to VARCHAR.

I tried executing the following queries:

```
select * cast(Patient_Number as varchar) from clinic_data;
select * from clinic_data cast(Patient_Number as varchar);
```

But only got the following error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cast(Patient_Number as char)' at line 1

Comment: `SELECT *`is not a good idea. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/14853083

Comment: It's not possible using `SELECT *`. You'll have to name all columns or `SELECT *` with a converted column added to the result that already contains an unconverted version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`SELECT *` is basically not a good idea

But you need  a comma, between both statements

And it should be char for the cast

```
select *, cast(Patient_Number as char) from clinic_data;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a6abd94c07ba1f1ff05030de902d91a)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, putting comma solved my problem

Comment: This returns two versions of `Patient_Number`.

Comment: no it doesn't it patientnumber is a number column the new one is character, additional to the old column, he doesn't explain why, but the answer is correct, i don't know why someone would downvote it